# Swift UI property not set the first time

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI and I am trying to use it together with UIKit.

I have this `UIViewControllerRepresentable` where I make a view controller which need a `product` property. The problem is that this property is nil the first time I tap on the selected view and then it works fine.

```
struct DetailController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    var product:Product?
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let detailVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: StringIdentifier.detailContainer.rawValue) as! DetailViewContainerViewController
        detailVC.product = product
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: detailVC)
        return navController
    }
}
```

the SwiftUI view:

```
struct CatalogueContentView: View {

 @ObservedObject var productList: ProductList
    @State private var isPresented = false
    @State var selectedProduct: Product?
    var gridItemLayout = [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]


    var body: some View {
        Spacer(minLength: 40)
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: gridItemLayout, spacing: 30) {
                ForEach(self.productList.data){ product in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10){
                        ImageView(withURL: product.image ?? "")
                        Text(product.name ?? "").font(.caption).foregroundColor(Color(.lightGray))
                        Text("$\(String(product.price ?? 0))").font(.title3).bold().foregroundColor(Color(.darkGray))
                    }.onTapGesture{
                        self.isPresented = true
                        self.selectedProduct = product // this is never nil when I tap
                    }.sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                        DetailController(product:self.selectedProduct)
                    }
                }.padding(.all, 10).background(Color(.white)).cornerRadius(10)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using `sheet(isPresented:` use `.sheet(item:`

```
.onTapGesture{
  //self.isPresented = true // No need this
    self.selectedProduct = product // this is never nil when I tap
}
.sheet(item: $selectedProduct) { (product)
    DetailController(product: product)
}
```